# Remove groups from People Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-search

How can I configure my query to only return people and exclude the groups that came from the AD?
My query now looks like this:

```
ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

Comment: are you using REST or SPFx search result webpart?